# BindingFlags for methods with Attributes

Tags: c#, metadata, bindingflags

Is it possible to use the `BindingFlags` for  methods that have attributes? I did look over msdn at `BindingFlags` and nothing showed up.
This is how one of my methods looks like :

```
[TestMethod()
,TestCategory("ActionCol")
,TestCategory("DataDriven")
,DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", @"|DataDirectory|\ActionCol\actionCol.csv", "actionCol#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)
,DeploymentItem(@"..\ActionCol\actionCol.csv")]
public void ActionCol_Insert_LeftGrid(){}
```

I am using reflection to add to a listbox all my void methods, but I want exclusively to add just the methods with this attribute..

This is how I am using `BindingFlags`:

```
methArr = e.myType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Where `methArr` is an `MethodInfo`-instance

Comment: why do you insist on using `BindingFlags` here, when you just want to check a usage of a specific attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding flags are not used in this case.

Instead what you must do is enumerate the methods for a given type and evaluate whether a method is decorated with a particular attribute.

The following code will find all of the methods of `myType` who are decorated with the `TestMethod` attribute using Linq:

```
var methArr =
    e.myType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
        .Where(method => method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (TestMethodAttribute), false).Any());
```